# Unable to use VisualStudio made static library with GCC

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I want to use a static library compiled with Visual Studio 2013 in CodeBlocks + GCC. But unfortunately i'm having some linking issues.

Then, I've made this sample code to try to obtain something working :

```
#include <iostream>    
void HelloWorld()    
{    
std::cout << "Hello World !" << std::endl;    
}
```

And I wrote the header too :

```
#pragma once    
void HelloWorld();
```

Unfortunately when trying to use it with GCC, compilation fails at the end (link edition).
Visual Studio compiles static libraries as .lib files, while all static libraries in MinGW/GCC folder are .a files. I've read somewhere that .a are pure static libraries when .lib can be static libraries or import library (for using DLLs).

Then, I don't know what should I do now ? Perhaps something in my code is wrong ? I admits that I'm not familiar with static libraries, as far as I'm not a regular VisualStudio user too.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ ABI (Application Binary Interface) is different between MSVC++ and gcc: you won't be able to call C++ functions from an object built within one compiler and defined in an object built with the other compiler. If you want to call function between the compilers you'll need to travel through a C interface (there *is* a C ABI on Windows) and hide the respective compiler-specific run-time libraries in a DLL.

Comment: Does it means just compiling .lib files as C code rather than C++ ? Or is it something more tricky ?

Comment: Well, it is certainly more tricky: you'll need to create a suitable C interface, export the corresponding functions while _not_ exporting others. I know that these things _can_ be done using DLLs and I think they _cannot_ be done using static linking. I haven't personally done the necessary setup, though, i.e., I don't know the details of actually doing it.